# Spring Integration listen on queue without poller

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I want to implement the HTTP endpoint using Spring Integration, which listen to the http requests, sends the request data as messages to the channel and another endpoint should listen messages on this channel and process them.

Sounds simple. But what I want to achieve is:

1. Messages should be processed in order.
2. Messages should be processed asap (without delay after http request, if the queue is already empty).
3. The http request should be responded as soon as message is received, not after it is processed, so the sender will know only that message is received for processing.
4. I don't want to use external queues, like RabbitMQ.

So I need a `QueueChannel` for this. But if I understand correctly, the only way to receive messages from the queue is the `poller`. So the point 2 will not be satisfied. There will be small delay after message received and before poller sees it.

So the question is: is there any simple way to achieve this in Spring Integration which I don't see?

Of course I can implement it myself. For example creating `SmartLifeCycle` component, which listen on `DirectChannel` and just put the messages into `java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue`, and also starts a dedicated thread which will wait on this queue and send the message into another `DirectChannel` for processing. So there will be no delay because thread will be unblocked as soon as `BlockingQueue` is not empty.

This all sounds like a "pattern" - some queue between two direct channels based on dedicated thread.

Maybe there is a simplier way, already implemented in Spring Integration, which I just don't see because of absense of expirience in this area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point 2 can be satisfied, even with a poller - just set the `fixed-delay` to 0 and/or increase the receive timeout (default 1 second); the poller thread will block in the queue until a message arrives; then immediately wait again.

You can also use an executor channel (the http thread hands off to the executor thread).

Comment: Thanks you, Gary! I didn't realize that `receiveTimeout` is actually a time, that poller's thread will wait new messages on an backing `BlockingQueue` until it release the Scheduler's thread. And after this, it will occupy the thread again according to poller's `Trigger` (`delay` for instance). So with delay of `0` and `receiveTimeout` of `1s` poller will block some Scheduler's thread almost all the time, and process messages asap! Thanks you very much!

*P.S. The executor channel with single-threaded executor using executor's internal queue is also a viable solution I didn't think of!

Comment: Bear in mind, either of these options could result in message loss, in the event of a server crash - use of some persistent store (such as rabbitmq) would be required if this is an issue for your application.

Comment: Yes, I know this. But message can be lost even when using RabbitMq. Network connection between caller and inbound http-endpoint, application crash after message received but before it was send into RabbitMq's queue, the caller's crash - just to name a few. So, instead of using an external queue (which won't guarantee "at least once" anyway) I better will schedule periodical fetching of all messages for last X minutes from the external source and proceed them idempotently. Some sort of "compensatory fetcher" to process possibly lost messages.

Comment: `>But message can be lost even when using RabbitMq.` - that's not strictly correct; you can use transactions or publisher confirms to verify the message arrived at the broker before returning the HTTP response. But that's fine - I just wanted to be sure you (or anyone reading this) was  aware.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is: the external system ("the caller" in my previous comment) which sends the http requests to my system doesn't care at all what I respond, or if I respond at all. :) So it won't resend the message (using another http request) to my system. Anyway, thanks you for all the responses! I read SI documentation before several times, but still doesn't fully undrestand how queue-channels work. After your answer I really understand it now.

Comment: Just don't set a `taskExecutor` at the same time. Otherwise, you'll end up in an infinite spam of runnables. Well, infinite until you run out of memory :-)