# Spring Integration multiple queue consumers

Tags: spring-integration

As a result of [Spring integration MessageQueue without polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44183584/spring-integration-messagequeue-without-polling), I have a poller that consumes messages from a queue instantly, using a custom TaskScheduler:

```
ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("resultProcessor-");

IntegrationFlows
  .from("inbound")
  .channel(MessageChannels.priority().get())
  .bridge(bridge -> bridge
    .taskScheduler(taskScheduler)
    .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(0).receiveTimeout(Long.MAX_VALUE)))
  .fixedSubscriberChannel()
  .route(inboundRouter())
  .get()
```

Now I'd like to have multiple threads consuming concurrently, so I tried:

```
ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("resultProcessor-");
scheduler.setPoolSize(4);
```

However, since in `AbstractPollingEndpoint` the task scheduler schedules a synchronous poller (it's a bit complicated), only 1 thread is created. If I set the TaskExecutor to anything but `SyncTaskExecutor` (default), I run into a flood of scheduled tasks (see [Spring integration MessageQueue without polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44183584/spring-integration-messagequeue-without-polling)).

How can I concurrently consume from a queue in Spring Integration? This seems pretty basic but I couldn't find a solution.

Instead of the queue I could use an `ExecutorChannel`, however, (AFAIK) I then lose queue features like priority, queue size, and metrics on which I rely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it like this:

- A single-threaded task scheduler that performs the polling
- A thread pool executor with a synchronous queue

This way, the task scheduler can give each executor 1 task and blocks when no executor is free, thus not draining the source queue or spamming tasks.

```
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow extractTaskResultFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
      .from(ChannelNames.TASK_RESULT_QUEUE)
      .bridge(bridge -> bridge
        .taskScheduler(taskResultTaskScheduler())
        .poller(Pollers
          .fixedDelay(0)
          .taskExecutor(taskResultExecutor())
          .receiveTimeout(Long.MAX_VALUE)))
      .handle(resultProcessor)
      .channel(ChannelNames.TASK_FINALIZER_CHANNEL)
      .get();
  }

  @Bean
  public TaskExecutor taskResultExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
      1, // corePoolSize
      8, // maximumPoolSize
      1L, // keepAliveTime
      TimeUnit.MINUTES,
      new SynchronousQueue<>(),
      new CustomizableThreadFactory("resultProcessor-")
    );
    executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new CallerBlocksPolicy(Long.MAX_VALUE));
    return new ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor(executor, errorHandler);
  }

  @Bean
  public TaskScheduler taskResultTaskScheduler() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("resultPoller-");
    return scheduler;
  }
```

(The initial example was copied from the linked question, this one now resembles my actual solution)

Answer (score 1):

See `PollerSpec.taskExecutor()`:

```
/**
 * Specify an {@link Executor} to perform the {@code pollingTask}.
 * @param taskExecutor the {@link Executor} to use.
 * @return the spec.
 */
public PollerSpec taskExecutor(Executor taskExecutor) {
```

This way after scheduling the task periodically according your `taskScheduler` and `delay`, the real task is performed on a thread from that provided executor. By default it indeed performs the task on a scheduler's thread.

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure if this meets your requirements, but this is only way to keep your queue logic and process whatever is pull in parallel:

```
 .bridge(bridge -> bridge
    .taskScheduler(taskScheduler)
    .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(0).receiveTimeout(Long.MAX_VALUE)))
 .channel(channels -> channel.executor(threadPoolExecutor()))   
 .fixedSubscriberChannel()
```

Comment: But if the task scheduler's delay is 0, it sends thousands of polling tasks to the task executor within seconds?

Comment: Well, technically, yes, but that is your configuration. What else would you expect? Another way really would be to use an `ExecutorChannel` after that `bridge()`, so only real pulled messages are going to be processed in parallel. But again: what is the point of priority then if you would like to process in parallel?

Comment: Right now, about 700k messages queue up and high prio messages should be processed first. What I'd expect is a way to have multiple consumers process those messages from the queue, without polling periodically - just like JMS consumers. If I bridge to an ExecutorChannel, all messages will instantly be sent to it defying the purpose of the priority queue, right?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Btw. I'm not sure why in the referenced Question I had a fixedSubscriberChannel(). I'm not using it anymore. Without it, having a taskScheduler and taskExecutor didn't work (not implying that it worked *with* it - I didn't test). Meanwhile I tried and succeeded with a different approach which posted I as an answer. Thank your help!